# Notepad++: How to remove text after second occurrence of comma using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've got text lines like

```
string1,email,string2,string3
```

How can I use regex to return the following?

```
string1,email
```

I want to remove everything that comes after the 2nd comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for:

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),.*$
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

Explanation:

`^` indicates the pattern should match from the start of a line.
`[^,]*,` is text that does not include a comma, followed by a comma. Two of these in a row gives you the first two items in your comma-separated list.
`.*$` is everything else in the line.
`\1` returns everything that matches the pattern inside the parentheses.

**EDIT in response to comment:**

To swap the email and string1, use this instead:

Search for:

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),.*$
```

and replace with:

```
\2,\1
```

The numbers correspond to the order of the parenthetical groups in the search pattern.

Comment: If you could add an explanation of how that regex works, that would be more helpful to others in the future.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Am i missing something ?

For example this is one line:
Senchak,joanna.senchak@gmail.com,Senchak,JoAnna

Comment: @Samuel I don't have Notepad++ on my computer, but this works in TextPad with slight syntax modification. What regex settings do you have in place?

Comment: Just tested it, it does work with the line that you provided. Make sure you have "Regex match" checked off.

Comment: Sorry Excelll, yea it was settings problem.
Worked fine in Regular Expressions Mode.
Thank you so much for such a quick solution.

Comment: There is one more thing.
Can i bring Email at first and String1 at 2nd like this?
From string1,Email to --->> Email,string1

Comment: @Samuel Yes, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

- In Notepad++ press **Ctrl + F**
- Select Tab: **Replace**
- Mark **regular expression** option
- Set in **Search:** `(.*),email,(.*)`
- **Replace with:** `\1,email`

Just rest to press Replace button.

Comment: You're making the likely incorrect assumption that `email` is the same literal string. It's probably an actual email (e.g. `a@example.com`, `b@example.com`), and different every line.

Comment: Exactly, It is different in every line.
Any other way to get around this problem?

Comment: then, answer #1 should be your solution, it works for me.