# Notepad++ : How to remove second occurrence of comma

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have text lines in **Notepad++** like below:

```
1122, String1, String2, 20202 
2222, String3, String4, 21212
3333, String5, String6, 3333333
4444, String8, String7, 44we23
```

I need to just remove second comma and get text like below:

```
1122, String1 String2, 20202 
2222, String3 String4, 21212
3333, String5 String6, 3333333
4444, String8 String7, 44we23
```

Though I referred to following post, I couldn't do it... :(
[similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/712268/notepad-how-to-remove-text-after-second-occurrence-of-comma-using-regex/712275#712275?newreg=5e223a8b8300448b83fd6861bea64e5a)

Thanks folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),(.*)$
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

Comment: Thanks @Adaaam.. it works like a charm. I just wanted to up vote the answer but it says I don't have enough reputation for that. Though I had 46, it now just shows 1. No idea where other reutation points went.

Comment: Looks like your 46 rep is for your SO account (this is SU)

Comment: What is SO and SU accounts. I just created one with my gmail account. What should be done now? I am confused

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow, the Stack Exchange forum for programming; SU is Super User (the site you're on), the forum for power computing. Post your questions in the appropriate forum and all will be well.

Comment: Why do we replace with \1

Answer (score 2):

Another regex to do this:

```
^(.*?,.*?),
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

Explanation:

`^.*?,` is a lazy (non-greedy) match of everything from the start of the line up to the first comma. This pattern is matched twice consecutively, so it catches everything up to the second comma.
The parentheses capture everything before the second comma.